# difference in the count of items displayed in site content and actual count of items

Tags: list, document-library, office-365, 2016

I have a list in Office 365

There are 70 items in it

But in the site content it keeps showing 76

What is causing this difference?

Its not a document library and there are no folders in the list

Comment: Have you performed batch delete recently on this document library?

Comment: No, i haven't deleted items recently
at least for last 5-6 days

Comment: Please check this link:http://joepreiner.com/library-list-item-counts-seem-wrong-sharepoint/

Comment: Is this just a custom list or survey list?

Answer (score 3):

You may use REST API by appending *_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('**MyList**')/Items*  to the Site collection url to get all items in the list. Example usage is :
http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('**MyList**')/Items

This will get all the list items in xml feed view. Currently I had 5 items in the list and the list items are shown along with their id. You can cross check and see what is causing the variance.
[image]

Comment: it only shows 70 and not the count that is shown in site contents

Comment: Check if there are items with unique permissions which is not visible to end users. Are you the site admin ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally what happens here is that there are documents in the library that were uploaded for the first time and never checked in, so only the owner of the files can see them no matter the view or permissions you have.

You can access the Library settings and then click on "Manage checked out files" / "Manage files which have no checked in version" and you will probably see the remaining files of the total number of items that SharePoint is seeing. Please refer to the below URL :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/bde7e1db-9720-4774-ab02-307c23438613/view-all-site-content-showing-the-wrong-number-of-items?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post, however I have recently discovered another cause of this issue. When you have a library with a **lookup column** to another list or library that is set to "**enforce relationship**", this also can cause the issue of altered count: when you delete a file in the library, SharePoint is not any more able to subtract this from the total count of items in the same library. This is a real bug, there is not other way than delete and recreate the library without the lookup enforcement... even if you try to deactivate this enforcement in the specific lookup column, the issue persists... Hope this help someone else, just in case please mark this as a correct answer